# Unable to hide js and map extension files in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2015

I know this question has been asked innumerable times but mostly it has targeted Visual studio code IDE not Visual Studio 2015.

I did the same as suggested for Visual Studio Code editor as shown below

settings.json

```
// Place your settings in this file to overwrite default and user settings.
{
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/.git": true,
        "**/.DS_Store": true,
      "**/*.js": { "when": "$(basename).ts" },
      "**/*.map": { "when": "$(basename).ts" }
    }, 
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay"
}
```

After placing these settings I restarted Visual Studio 2015 but I can still see files with js and map extensions. What can be done to just hide the files which are associated with ts extensions (if you know what I mean)?